# codebeamer and svn integration

Tags: svn, alm

I am trying to move from trac to codebeamer and have issue with integrating it with my svn repo.

while I can connect to svn repo - which has presently 48 revisions - codebeamer only shows 39 on the main screen. However, if I were to browse the files tab and go to a directory where I know I had committed stuff in latest rev and codebeamer gives the log for that file with latest rev (greater than 39). I cant seem to figure out what the issue can be.

Does anyone have idea on how to configure this properly ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the repo in codebeamer after going thru a fresh commit .. and now the new repo shows all the revisions. I could not figure out why this happened but things are OK now.

Comment: The only difference I guess  was that I had put the repo name as Folder name while configuring the repo the first time. That may have restricted the change list to that particular folder only. It was confusing since my repo name and project names are same ... and I have a project name directory as well. Just a guess till someone confirms it.